# I'd like to find out year this bicycle was made — it's a lady's Schwinn

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

Lady's Schwinn. Serial number is B340240.

[image: Schwinn bike]

Comment: I appreciate any help you can give me in reference to the year of this Schwinn bicycle Thank you

Comment: A picture of the whole bike would be nice.  But the "tank" strongly suggests a birth date earlier than 1970.

Comment: Or you could just Google it: https://bikehistory.org/serial-number.html

Answer (score 5):

According to http://bikehistory.org/schwinn.php?serial=B340240:

> Your bike is an original Chicago Schwinn. Built: 02/22 of 1963

The site from Daniel Hicks says it was built February 22, 1963 and is an original Chicago Schwinn.

Comment: Thank you so much .. this bike is in Very good condition.its missing the bolt for the seat post clamp and rear reflector .it was a abandoned garage find ( no house) the tires hold air  ! So I took it for a spin it's Awesome ..I tried posting picture of whole bike but it would on only download part . It is 4sale $125.00